# Add two numbers with Excel VBA function called from a c++ .dll

Tags: c++, excel, vba, excel-formula

I am using Excel Version 2206 Build 16.0.15330.20260 (64-bit) and Visual Studio Community 2022.

I am trying to call functions from a .dll in VBA.

I built my VBA module and .dll from this tutorial: https://scriptreference.com/interfacing-a-c-dll-with-excel-2016-using-visual-studio-2019/ where one reference is passed through the function.

When I added my own function to add two numbers by passing in two references, the VBA wrapper function I made in Excel returns zero.

I tried to find more resources online, such as .dll functions using multiple parameters in Excel VBA.

My source .cpp file looks like this:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "SquareLib.h"

double WINAPI get_square(double* x) //function copied from tutorial that works
{
    return *x * *x;
}

double WINAPI add_nums(double* x, double* y) //my function
{
    return *x + *y;
}
```

The header file:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef SQUARELIB_EXPORTS
#define SQUARELIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SQUARELIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


extern "C" SQUARELIB_API double get_square(double* x);
extern "C" SQUARELIB_API double add_nums(double* x, double* y);
```

I compiled and built my solution in VS as a x64 bit .dll.

The code in VBA/Excel:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function get_square_cpp _
  Lib "C:\Users\artil\source\repos\SquareLib\x64\Debug\SquareLib.dll" Alias "get_square" _
  (ByRef my_var As Double) As Double

Declare PtrSafe Function add_nums_cpp _
  Lib "C:\Users\artil\source\repos\SquareLib\x64\Debug\SquareLib.dll" Alias "add_nums" _
  (ByRef x As Double, ByRef y As Double) As Double

Function get_square(x As Double) 'square wrapper function
    get_square = get_square_cpp(x)
End Function

Function add_num(x As Double, y As Double) 'add_num wrapper function
    add_nums = add_nums_cpp(x, y)
End Function
```

When I call the wrapper function add_num() as a formula in Excel, it returns 0, instead of adding the two numbers.

I looked online to see whether I'm using pointers incorrectly. I didn't find anything saying my c++ function shouldn't work.

Comment: Can you show the VBA/Excel code for `get_square`? Currently your question only shows vba/excel code for `add_num`. Just add the vba/excel code for `get_square` in your question. Additonally, try creating a separate header, source and vba file for `add_num` and then trying again. I mean currently you have both `add_num` and `get_square` in the same header and source file. Just separate them to different files(both header and source as well as vba/excel differently) and see if that works. Also take care of the filename you're using like `SquareLib.dll` or `AddNumLib.dll`

Comment: @JasonLiam I added the get_square VBA code, both the declaration of the .dll and the wrapper function.

Comment: I also made a separate header and source file, moved the AddNum functions/code to both a new .dll project and Excel, however the functions still returns zero when I attempt to use the wrapper formula.

Comment: I think you're missing an `s` at the end. In particular, `Function add_num(x As Double, y As Double)` should be `Function add_nums(x As Double, y As Double)` . Note that i've added an `s` in the above replacement.

Answer (score 0):

There was a simple spelling error for the name of the *wrapper function* in VBA/Excel. `add_nums()` was missing an `s` at the end. Thanks to @jasonliam for spotting it.

Comment: seriously SERIOUSLY